# Access Switchboard Manager: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to update an existing Switchboard in an Access database. When I click the "Switchboard Manager" button, I get the error "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument." Any ideas what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switchboard manager stores your settings in a table named `Switchboard Items`.  Open that table in Datasheet View, and see whether you can spot any stored values which don't make sense.  Sorry, I can't tell you specifically what doesn't make sense ... hopefully you'll know when/if you see it.

Actually that error message sounds to me more like a problem with the form itself.  So rename the form and table, and create a new switchboard, which will also create a new copy of the `Switchboard Items` table.

If that new form/table combination works correctly, delete or rename the new copy of `Switchboard Items`.  Then rename the old saved version of that table back to `Switchboard Items` again and try it with your new form.  If the problem was solely due to the form, your new clean copy of the form should now work with the original version of `Switchboard Items`.

Note that many Access developers avoid the switchboard manager.  It is limited and brittle.  You can substitute custom forms which command buttons for your menu options.  That may seem like more work, but it's not a huge amount of extra work, and you will be protected against switchboard manager breakage.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to determine that the switchboard table has 10 items instead of the 8 that Switchboard Manager allows.